# How to perform fast merging c++ list with itself

Tags: c++, visual-studio, list

Lets say I have a list containing some integers, I need to quickly merge it with itself : for example I have {1, 2, 3} after that procedure I want the list to be {1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3}
These versions do that but too slow when list size is big enough (10^6)

```
    list< int > l;    //l got some integers here         
    list< int > l_copy = l;

    while (l_copy.size() > 0)
    {
        l.push_back(l_copy.front());
        l_copy.pop_front();
    }

    //another version but still slow i think
    size_t size = l.size();
    for (list<int>::iterator it = l.begin(); size--; ++it)
    {
        l.push_back(*it);
    }
```

Is there any alternatives for doing this but significantly faster?
thanks

Comment: What about making a copy of the list, then splicing the copy onto the original?

Comment: Lists inherently involve a dynamic memory allocation per node, so extending them will never be fast.  You might want to consider whether e.g. `deque` is adequate to your needs - at least it groups the elements into a lesser number of contiguous allocations.  Alternatively, for some uses you might be able to use a custom allocator that visits elements twice....

Comment: It may be irrelevant but what is the purpose of the doubling up? You could create a container/iterator that *acts* like a list doubled up.

Comment: Can you use vector? It might be faster.

Comment: @NeilKirk I think vector would be a bit risky to use because the number of merge operations reach about million, so vector with his reallocations could slow down the speed

Comment: List performs memory allocation for *every* element. Vector only sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::list::splice` for this:

```
list<int> l;
list<int> l_copy = l;    
l.splice (l.end(), l_copy);
```

That version of `splice` is guaranteed to work in constant time by the standard (§23.3.5.5/6 in n4296). It works by just pointing the end of the first list at the beginning of the other list. There is another version of splice which uses iterator ranges which is O(n), but that isn't needed here. Obviously the copy will still take time for a large list, but that's unavoidable.

Comment: hmm thanks good idea, but why splice works at constant time? As I see from its source code it uses iterations from  first to last iterator, so it depends of list size how much iterations would be